# How to stretch timber framing in Revit using reference planes

Tags: cad, revit

I'm creating a family in Revit 2011, I've imported some timber framing components and placed a series of instances into the model.

I then placed a reference plane at each end of the timber framing and aligned them with the two planes and locked them. I expected to be able to move one reference plane and the timber would stretch to suit, however the timber wants to keep its existing lenght and so Revit throws up an error.

How can i make the timber stretch with the reference

Answer (score 1):

1st. In most cases you will need to have the length parameter inside the nested (term for family loaded inside family) set as 'instance'.

2nd. Make sure that the dimensions in the nested family are referencing 'Reference Lines' or 'Reference Planes' to expose them to the host family (references to geometry will not be accessible in the host family).

3nd. when aligning the framing to your reference planes ensure that you are aligning to a 'reference' (information of preselected object is in the bottom left) not geometry.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I recommend updating Revit. The last 2 versions 2016 & 2017 are much faster than previous versions. The Beam template has also been updated and works much better than previous versions.

You can stretch the out of the box beams in quite a few ways.

1 *Align* the end of the beam to your **reference plane** and *lock*. Make sure that you are selecting the '**shape handle**' when aligning or the relationship will break. The '**Status Bar**' bottom right of the UI provides feedback on what you are hovering over when the *align tool* is active. If you move the **reference plane** the beam should stretch.

2 Make sure you have a structural element at the ends of your beam. A **Structural** wall (there is a instance parameter named this), a **Beam** or **Column** that you *Trim* to or *Drag* the end to, should clean up and cut back the **Beam**. Once this relationship is established the **Beam** should stretch when you *move* the the intersection object.

3 Use a *Dimension* string to adjust the length. Place a dimension string, and make sure you are dimensioning to the '**Shape Handle**' of each end. After placing the *Dimension* you can select the beam, and the *dimension* value should be blue and you can select and change the value.

4 Create a *beam system*. This allows you to define the perimeter of a set of parallel beams, and control placement, spacing, etc.. If you adjust the perimeter of the system, the beams automatically adjust.

I hope this helps.